# Use a variable defined in a method inside the template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

it's the first time I use Vue (v2 not v3) and I'm stucked trying to use a variable (defined inside a methods) inside the template.

My semplified code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container" @mouseover="isHovered = true" @mouseleave="isHovered = false">
    <div class="c-container">
      <div ref="topCContainerRef" class="top-c-container">
        <div
          :class="['top-c', ...]"
          :style="{ height: `${isHovered ? 0 : this.scaledHeight}` }" // <-- HERE I need `scaledHeight`
        >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale'

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  components: {  },
  props: {
    ...,
    datum: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    ...
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      isHovered: false,
      scaledHeight: {},
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.matchHeight()
  },
  methods: {
    matchHeight() {
      const topCContainerHeight = this.$refs.topCContainerRef.clientHeight
      const heightScale = scaleLinear([0, 100], [20, topCContainerHeight])
      const scaledHeight = heightScale(this.datum)
      this.scaledHeight = scaledHeight // I want to use this value inside the template
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

How can I get the value of `scaledHeight` inside the template section?

If I didn't use `this`, I get no error but the height value is always 0, like `scaledHeight` is ignored..

I read the documentation but it doesn't help me

Comment: what type does heightScale return? is it a number?

Comment: you can do `:style="{ height: isHovered ? 0 : scaledHeight }"`, but the issue is most likely that you're setting it as an object in data and its not reactive

Comment: actually logic suggests it should be `:style="{ height: isHovered ? scaledHeight : 0}"` else it would be 0 when hovered and scaledHeight when not, which may be 0

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you for the answer but `:style="{ height: isHovered ? scaledHeight : 0}"` is not the solution because isHovered depends on a parent div that has always a fixed height. Yes,  `heightScale` is a number

Comment: ok, try in data `scaledHeight: 0,`

Comment: I tried. It still doesn't work...

Comment: then maybe heightScale simply returns 0, your question is: *Use a variable defined in a method inside the template*. we are presuming you have tested that everything works except what your asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using `computed`

```
computed: {
    computedHeight: function () {
      return this.isHovered ? 0 : this.matchHeight()
    },
},
methods: {
    matchHeight() {
      const topCContainerHeight = this.$refs.topCContainerRef.clientHeight
      const heightScale = scaleLinear([0, 100], [20, topCContainerHeight])
      return heightScale(this.datum)
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered and solved this problem today.
You can change your styles like below.

```html
<div
    :class="['top-c', ...]"
    :style="{ height: isHovered ? 0 : scaledHeight }" 
>
```

It works fine for me, and hope it will help you~~

Comment: Thank you Sarah, but it still doesn't work. No errors but height is always 0

Comment: The `scaledHeight` should be a number, and you can try to add `px` after it. like this: ```<div
    :class="['top-c', ...]"
    :style="{ height: isHovered ? 0 : scaledHeight + 'px'}" 
>```